# An error occured while checking mobile data state

Tags: java, android

I want to check the mobile data state on/off in android.
I have written the below code in button clicking code..

```
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public void check_mobile_data(View view) { // this is my button clicking event.
    Context context = null;

    boolean mobileDataEnabled = false; // Assume disabled
    @SuppressWarnings("null")
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    try {

        Class cmClass = Class.forName(cm.getClass().getName());

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Method method = cmClass.getDeclaredMethod("getMobileDataEnabled");
        method.setAccessible(true); // Make the method callable
        // get the setting for "mobile data"
        mobileDataEnabled = (Boolean) method.invoke(cm);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        // Some problem accessible private API
        // TODO do whatever error handling you want here
    }

    if (mobileDataEnabled == true) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ON", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }
    if (mobileDataEnabled == false) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "OFF", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }
}
```

The below error is showed by the logcat

```
02-19 11:08:29.338: E/AndroidRuntime(14900): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-19 11:08:29.338: E/AndroidRuntime(14900): Process: com.example.checkmobiledata, PID: 14900
02-19 11:08:29.338: E/AndroidRuntime(14900): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
02-19 11:08:29.338: E/AndroidRuntime(14900):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4012)
02-19 11:08:29.338: E/AndroidRuntime(14900):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4761)
02-19 11:08:29.338: E/AndroidRuntime(14900):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19767)
02-19 11:08:29.338: E/AndroidRuntime(14900):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
02-19 11:08:29.338: E/AndroidRuntime(14900):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
02-19 11:08:29.338: E/AndroidRuntime(14900):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
02-19 11:08:29.338: E/AndroidRuntime(14900):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
02-19 11:08:29.338: E/AndroidRuntime(14900):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-19 11:08:29.338: E/AndroidRuntime(14900):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
02-19 11:08:29.338: E/AndroidRuntime(14900):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
02-19 11:08:29.338: E/AndroidRuntime(14900):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
02-19 11:08:29.338: E/AndroidRuntime(14900): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
02-19 11:08:29.338: E/AndroidRuntime(14900):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-19 11:08:29.338: E/AndroidRuntime(14900):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
02-19 11:08:29.338: E/AndroidRuntime(14900):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4007)
02-19 11:08:29.338: E/AndroidRuntime(14900):    ... 10 more
02-19 11:08:29.338: E/AndroidRuntime(14900): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
02-19 11:08:29.338: E/AndroidRuntime(14900):    at com.example.checkmobiledata.MainActivity.check_mobile_data(MainActivity.java:28)
02-19 11:08:29.338: E/AndroidRuntime(14900):    ... 13 more
```

Please give me reply at your best.

Comment: `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference` what does this tell you?

Comment: add android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE permission

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method ... Context.getSystemService...

Because `context` object is `null`. not initializing before using `context` object for accessing `getSystemService` method.

use `view.getContext()` for getting context:

```
 Context context = view.getContext();
```

Comment: Dear ρяσѕρєя K, i have initialize the context variable but, when press button it always shows you "OFF" while i have switch on mobile data for the mobile network

Comment: @cheelstar: have you added `android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` permission?

Comment: Dear ρяσѕρєя K, It works, i have forget to add the permission. Thanks and best regards

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK u there i am having same issue in Listview adapter can u please suggest me how to fix it  please look my adapter http://paste.ofcode.org/pJtDrE6xPESEMfYnVQmiCk